# How do I permanently disable notifications about Auto capture keyboard and Mouse pointer integration for a Virtualbox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, mouse, virtualization

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a VirtualBox VM. Now every time I boot it, I get two overlay notifications from VirtualBox:

> You have the **Auto capture keyboard** option turned on. This will
>   cause the Virtual Machine to automatically **capture** the keyboard
>   every time the VM window is activated and make it unavailable to other
>   applications running on your host machine: when the keyboard is
>   captured, all keystrokes (including system ones like Alt-Tab) will be
>   directed to the VM.  (...)

and

> The Virtual Machine reports that the guest OS supports **mouse pointer
>   integration**. This means that you do not need to *capture* the mouse
>   pointer to be able to use it in your guest OS — all mouse actions you
>   perform when the mouse pointer is over the Virtual Machine’s display
>   are directly sent to the guest OS. If the mouse is currently captured,
>   it will be automatically uncaptured.

These overlay notifications persist from the start of boot untill I click `☓` on them.

**Can I disable them permanently?**

I'm runnung VirtualBox 5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64).

Comment: I don't have the screen in front of me but I seem to remember that there were two small icons in the corner of these messages: one X, and one that looked like a crossed-out balloon. You would click the latter, obviously.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Now I feel silly. Please make it an answer, in case someone else will not figure it out (though there's a hint on hover).

Comment: No need to feel silly, that seems like a bubble denoting information. The line on some displays or platforms might be less visible (guess) and busy ones will not notice a few times clicking the visible cross. That's bad user interface design.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove the message once: click the X button.

To remove the message once and for all: click the crossed-out balloon next to the X.

To reinstate these messages, go to Settings -> User Interface -> File - Reset all warnings (this is my translation, could be slightly different).

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a script, such as with vboxmanage?

Comment: Apparently there is a scriptable command:
`VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SuppressMessages "all"`
but it doesn't seem to be documented ... discovered via https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25797&hilit=disable+notification

Oddly, this option is not showing up in the list provided by `vboxmanage getextradata <uuid|vmname> enumerate`

Comment: Looks like getting the precise details on how to suppress messages requires reviewing the source code per https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=66523

Listing global options is possible with `VBoxManage getextradata global enumerate`

Answer (score 4):

Moving my comment into an answer:

`VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SuppressMessages "all"`

You can see a more granular view of the possible values for GUI/SuppressMessages with `VBoxManage getextradata global enumerate` - mine looked like:

> confirmInputCapture,remindAboutAutoCapture,remindAboutMouseIntegrationOff,remindAboutMouseIntegrationOn,remindAboutWrongColorDepth

before I set it to `all`.

I figured this out from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25797&hilit=disable+notification and https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=66523 but apparently `all` is not documented and was discovered by reading the source.

Comment: might be better to delete the comment if so.

Comment: I believe comments cannot be deleted after a certain period of time.